# Fetch data is shown in console.log, but not in HTML TAG

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api, innerhtml

I'm trying to fetch a JSON data from our server and then inserting it in a `<script>` TAG in **client-side**. See below:

```
<script>
    const bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    const url = "https://ourAPI.com";
    const parameters = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers(),
        mode: "cors",
        cache: "default",
    };

    fetch(url, parameters).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            response.json().then((data) => {
                console.log(data.imports);   //It shows me data fetched.
                const importmap = document.createElement("script");
                importmap.type = "systemjs-importmap";
                importmap.innerHTML = data.imports;   //It shows me "[object Object]".
                bodyTag.appendChild(importmap);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

The problem is: when I `console.log(data.imports)`, it shows me the fetched data, but the `<script>` TAG looks like this:

```
<script type="systemjs-importmap">[object Object]</script>
```

What it looks strange for me is when I use `JSON.stringify(data)`, it is possible to see that the data was extracted from the API as expected (see below), but in JSON format it doesn't extract anything...

```
<script type="systemjs-importmap"> ...all data in string format... </script>
```

Could anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you assign to `innerHTML` will be implicitly converted to a string. Hence, the `[object Object]` you're seeing. In order to see the actual JSON value, you can explicitly convert this object to a JSON-string:

```js
importmap.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.imports);
```

Comment: Right... well, the goal is to create this script with type "systemJS-importmap" in which it only accepts JSON format. Is it possible to somehow insert JSON instead of string?

Comment: That's what `JSON.stringify` does @FábioMatsu. It creates JSON from a JS data structure. JSON _is_ a string.

Comment: Yup, what @Andy said

Comment: Ohh... you guys are right. It's working! Now I have a dynamice importmaps. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `importmap.innerText = JSON.stringify(data.imports);` instead. InnerHtml expects an HTML string which data.imports just isn't. At that point your JSON object is being serialized as [object Object] because the browser just doesn't know how else to represent the object.

Comment: Yes! That's was my mistake. Thank you!